# Swift getting the user's tapped location from mapkit

Tags: swift3, location, mapkit

I am trying to get the coordinates longitude and lattitude of the tapped location on mapkit however, there doesnt seem to be anything printing out

here's the part of my code:

```
@IBAction func revealRegionDetailsWithLongPressOnMap(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
if sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.began { return }
let touchLocation = sender.location(in: protectedMapView)
let locationCoordinate = protectedMapView.convert(touchLocation, toCoordinateFrom: protectedMapView)
print("Tapped at lat: \(locationCoordinate.latitude) long: \(locationCoordinate.longitude)")
}
```

I have a long press gesture recognizer on my mapkit's viewcontroller and have connected it to the IBAction by cntrl dragging it to First Responder.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you mean nothing as in no printout, or it prints but w/o a location?  Your code here looks OK, so is it a matter of the gesture recognizer not working or the location part not working?  For comparison, here's what I use after getting a call that passes through the .began test: coordinate = mapView.convert(sender.location(in: mapView), toCoordinateFrom: mapView)

Comment: In particular, did you include UIGestureRecognizerDelegate for your view controller?